# How to embed image in a js file from url?

Tags: javascript

I wanna need to see this picture in my site from the below url

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoyZ-M6C9WpiR6MlWAZ0sNTiXsDWM8_ln3WA&usqp=CAU

And I wanna do this for my rest api project. After entering text instead of this my private textmaker link must show the result image like this in my website, this is What I needed!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function add_img() { 
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoyZ-M6C9WpiR6MlWAZ0sNTiXsDWM8_ln3WA&usqp=CAU'; 
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);
}
```